# Restrict ImportRange to only visible rows

Tags: google-sheets, importrange, google-sheets-filter

I need to restrict the ImportRange function below to show only visible rows as some of the rows are filtered and some of the rows are grouped.

```
=importrange("WorkbookID","Sheet1!A2:K13285")
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/98889/199004) answer.

1. Create a new sheet within the same document
2. Use filter function (Set the `A1` cell to be `=filter(Sheet1!A:X, Sheet1!A:A>1)`). (See docs on the filter function.)
3. Import range from this new sheet.

Answer (score 1):

At this time IMPORTRANGE can't import only visible rows. Currently there isn't any built-in function that does that and this can't be done by using a custom function as accesing an external range require authorization and custom functions can't use methods that require it.

The alternative is to use another kind of script, and add-on or a third party application.