# I want to bring in already filtered data into a new spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange, google-sheets-filter

Is it possible to reference filtered data from one sheet to another in Google Sheets?

I use the filter button to sort in a master sheet. I then use this formula in a new sheet:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("urlofthemastersheet", "sheetname!A1:A")
```

That formula is referencing and showing everything from column A in the master sheet in the new sheet. After I filter the data in the master sheet, the new sheet still shows all of column A.

How do I get the new sheet to only show what is filtered within the master sheet?

The point of the new sheet is to have our logo, contact info, and rows highlighted on it so if we need to share with clients it looks more professional.

Comment: Welcome. _"Is it possible to reference filtered data from one sheet to another?"_. Yes it is (depending on how and what you filtered). Still. Please share a test sheet with some data and expected results so we can help.

Comment: "This is my formula in the new sheet." Which formula, which sheet?

Comment: This formula is being used in the new sheet and linking to the master sheet

Comment: Could you share a sheet? We cannot tell what the formula filters. Also. Please edit your question instead of writing the formula as a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your edits. I am afraid though you are doing it the wrong way. As mentioned before there are several ways to filter data. So, I have to insist on you to **share a test sheet** with data and expected results. That way we can also avoid this back and forth on comments and move on to solving the issue you face.

Comment: _"I use the **filter button** to sort in a master sheet. I then use this formula ... referencing and showing everything from column A in the master sheet in the new sheet. After I filter the data in the master sheet, the new sheet still shows all of column A."_ Of course. **You would need to somehow filter data using formulas and functions in your master sheet. Not by using the filter button.**

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Is it possible to reference filtered data from one sheet to another in google sheets?
>
> I am using the filter button to sort in a master sheet. I am then using this formula in a new sheet: =IMPORTRANGE("urlofthemastersheet", "sheetname!A1:A")

It's not possible by using `IMPORTRANGE` but you could import that data by using Google Apps Script.

Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

---

In Google Sheets there are several ways to filter data.

If you are using the filters / filter views, as it was mentioned above, it's not possible to reference the filtered data by using `IMPORTRANGE`. One alternative is is to use functions like FILTER/SOR/QUERY , i.e. `=FILTER(A:D, LEN(A:A)`, instead of the filter/filter views.

Example

Considering that your data is in `sheetname!A1:A`

1. Add a new sheet to the spreadsheet that holds the data and name it `Filtered Data`.
2. Add the following formula to `'Filtered Data'!A1`:

   ```
   =FILTER(sheetname!A1:A,sheetname!A1:A>1)
   ```

   > The above is just an example to illustrate the steps to follow. Replace this formula for the one that filter/sort your data the way you need.
3. In your spreadsheet where you are importing the data, instead of

   ```
   =IMPORTRANGE("urlofthemastersheet", "sheetname!A1:A")
   ```

   use

   ```
   =IMPORTRANGE("urlofthemastersheet", "Filtered Data!A1")
   ```

Related

- [How to export a filtered set of rows from a Google Spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/30300/88163)
- [Restrict ImportRange to only visible rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/121968/88163)

Comment: This is my formula in the new sheet. =IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N9ur-jZweAC7CvnowI0DEkgGahynHEn03QCTdZEmCAg/edit#gid=101600334", "Calculator!A1:A") Could you explain how the =Filter would be used in this?

Comment: Very well said. Hopefully the answer covers all the _"ifs"_ you may have and can now solve your issue.

Comment: @KatherineWithrow-Mielo Please look at https://support.google.com/docs for the Google Sheets functions list, there it should be listed FILTER and include a link to help article about how to use it. If you need further help with how to use this function, please post a new question. Tip: Create a spreadsheet that includes a sample input data and your attempt to use FILTER, and share it with anyone with the link can View. In the body of the question include the link to your spreadsheet, your formula using FILTER and describe what is the result that you are looking for.

Comment: @KatherineWithrow-Mielo I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I think what I am trying to achieve are more along the lines of this question, which is not doable. I appreciate the effort in helping me though! https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/121968/restrict-importrange-to-only-visible-rows.